# .net listbox add onrowdatabound event - how?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I would like to extend the listbox on my .net page and add an onrowdatabound event and I am wondering if I can do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it would be valuable to do this on a per-row basis, rather than just capturing DataBinding and doing whatever you want there. But if you really wanted to do this, then just iterate through the data source and raise an event:

```
public class ItemDataBoundArgs: EventArgs
{
   public object Item;
}
public class MyListBox: ListBox
{
    public event EventHandler ItemDataBound;
    protected override void OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
    {
       base.OnDataBinding(e);
       if (ItemDataBound != null)
       {
           foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)DataSource)
           {
                var e= new ItemDataBoundArgs();
                e.Item=item;
                ItemDataBound(this,e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this requires DataSource to be IEnumerable, which it doesn't have to be, so you could check for that too.

This sounds like an interview question...

Comment: No its not an interview question.  I am trying to add a 'title' to each of the rows in the list, much like a tooltip and I know how to do it with the gridview using the rowbound event but don't know how to do the same with a listbox.

Comment: Couldn't you just do it after the control has been created, and iterate through the Items collection?

Comment: Funny you should say that, that's is exactly what I did do in the end.  Thanks.